# Converting month names to actual months

Tags: reportingservices-2005, report-designer

Sorry for the odd title, not sure how else to summarize the issue.

I'm working with Report Designer 1.0 in SSRS 2005.

I have month names (e.g. January, February, etc) that I have extracted from a longer string that I am using in a 'Month' column of a table using this in the Edit Expression box:

```
=Mid(Fields!DESCRIPTION.Value, InStrRev(Fields!DESCRIPTION.Value, " ") + 1)
```

I now need to put the months in chronological order.  Can anyone help?

Many thanks,
Jens

Comment: Any takers?  The problem here is that the months in this case are just simple strings, i.e. there's no metadata that would help to order them properly.